# Find minimum distance in a set of objects in R or Python

Tags: python, r, geocoding, geospatial, geocode

I have a set of counties along with the latitude and longitude of each centroid:

```
county    lat       lon 
Abiline   32.134   -23.322
Cook      43.324   -32.219
Allegheny 31.949   -30.123
```

I also have a list of many hospitals, with each hospital's longitude and latitude. I want to find the distance to the closest hospital for each county centroid.

So far, I've used geocode() function from ggmap to find each county's distance to each hospital, and then choose the minimum distance. However, because I have many counties and many hospitals, the problem becomes high dimensional very quickly and can take a long time.

I'd like to avoid using arcgis for this - is there a straightforward way to do this in R or Python?

Comment: Are you looking for the euclidian distance?

Comment: If you're looking for the minimum euclian distance in R, you can use `min(dist(c(df$lat,df$lon)))`

Comment: Yes, I am looking for Euclidean distance. In your solution, does `df$lat` and `df$lon` refer to stacked (lat, lon) pairs of every hospital and county?

Comment: Yes, it should return a pair-wise matrix of distances

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to achieve is something like this question
[closest pair of points](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/closest-pair-of-points/) here is the complete algorithm and explanation to achieve the same:

> We are given an array of n points in the plane, and the problem is to find out the closest pair of points in the array. This problem arises in a number of applications. For example, in air-traffic control, you may want to monitor planes that come too close together, since this may indicate a possible collision. Recall the following formula for distance between two points p and q.
>   The Brute force solution is O(n^2), compute the distance between each pair and return the smallest. We can calculate the smallest distance in O(nLogn) time using Divide and Conquer strategy.

**Algorithm**

Following are the detailed steps of a O(n (Logn)^2) algortihm.
Input: An array of n points P[]
Output: The smallest distance between two points in the given array.

As a pre-processing step, input array is sorted according to x coordinates.

1. Find the middle point in the sorted array, we can take P[n/2] as middle point.
2. Divide the given array in two halves. The first subarray contains points from P[0] to P[n/2]. The second subarray contains points from P[n/2+1] to P[n-1].
3. Recursively find the smallest distances in both subarrays. Let the distances be dl and dr. Find the minimum of dl and dr. Let the minimum be d.
4. Recursively find the smallest distances in both subarrays. Let the distances be dl and dr. Find the minimum of dl and dr. Let the minimum be d.
5. Sort the array strip[] according to y coordinates. This step is O(nLogn). It can be optimized to O(n) by recursively sorting and merging.
6. Find the smallest distance in strip[]. This is tricky. From first look, it seems to be a O(n^2) step, but it is actually O(n). It can be proved geometrically that for every point in strip, we only need to check at most 7 points after it (note that strip is sorted according to Y coordinate).
7. Finally return the minimum of d and distance calculated in above step (step 6)

**Implementation** [is here](https://gist.github.com/jsjain007/c3c1f84aca27651c5c4a2ca2c9cb2fac)

hope this helps :)

Source: Geeksforgeeks.org